# How to make Objects fall out of the sky randomly and then delete themselves when they go off-screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

For Unity (Lastest Version & C#)

1. How do I make an object fall from the sky at random places (random x but fixed y) in a 2D game
2. How do I delete them when they get off-screen and create a timing between objects falling

Whenever I run the program it randomly creates object but keeps naming them this: myObj, myObj(Clone), myObj(Clone)(Clone), myObj(Clone)(Clone)(Clone) every time a new object is instantiated. More importantly the instantiate part keeps running, spawning a bunch of objects and not deleting them.

Also, I just don't get how to delete the objects as soon as they get out of from the camera. Do I have to create a different script for it or smthn?

```
public class RandomObjectsFalling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    public float timebeforedie = 1f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBlocks());
    }


    IEnumerator SpawnBlocks()
    {
        while(x <= 1)
        {
            float randomPosition = Random.Range(-10f, 10f);
            GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randomPosition, 8, 0), Quaternion.identity); //problem is this keeps getting called creating a whole bunch of objects but they don't get destroyed
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timebeforedie);
            Destroy(clone);
        }
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `x` declared? Where is `x` incremented in the loop?

Comment: @Klompengard within a Coroutine and endless loop would actually be fine as long as you `yield` somewhere within

Comment: If you want to destroy the GameObject after some time, you can use `Destroy(clone, timebeforedie);` and it will destroy itself after that time. Then you can use a yield return with just the time between when they spawn, so you can have more than one at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to Spawn Your Obj

```
public GameObject prefab;
public bool startSpawning;
public float spawnDelay;
private float _currentSpawnDelay;

private void Start()
{
    _currentSpawnDelay = spawnDelay;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (startSpawning)
    {
        _currentSpawnDelay -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (_currentSpawnDelay < 0)
        {
            _currentSpawnDelay = spawnDelay;
            var randomPosition = Random.Range(-10f, 10f);
            Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randomPosition, 8, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

And This To Destroy Them But This Code Need To be Attach On Obj You That you want to Spawn

```
    private void Update()
{
    if (gameObject.transform.position.x < -20)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Attach The Destroy Code to your Obj Prefab